# Dose Flutter Freezed have toMap() method ? if not how I can add?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, freezed, flutter-freezed

In this model when i use freezed i'm missing `toMap()` method

I want change the company object into `Map<String, String>`

```dart
class Company {
  final String? id;
  final String? name;

  Company({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  Map<String, String> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id!,
      'name': name!,
    };
  }

  factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Company(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fromJson`|`toJson` methods can be generated automatically based on your fields. I recommend that you pay attention to this section of the documentation - [Freezed: FromJson/ToJson](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#fromjsontojson)

Your model will end up looking something like this:

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'company.freezed.dart';
part 'company.g.dart';

@freezed
class Company with _$Company {
  const factory Company({
    required String? id,
    required String? name,
  }) = _Company;

  factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      => _$CompanyFromJson(json);
}
```

Now all you have to do is run the command in the console:

```bash
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

If you need exactly `toMap()` method with that name, you can do it like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => toJson();
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay. if i'm not wrong toJson() will give <String, dynamic> right?

but I want Map<String, String> 

in this case how the freezed model should be ?

chatGPT gave me a solution like this and it's working I just want to confirm is this approach is correct ? 

(https://chat.openai.com/share/228fc6ad-029c-4490-a8d6-f04c01b807d8)

Comment: Typically your json has values of different types. Therefore, the word `dynamic` is used. Specifically in this case, when you are certain that your fields will only be `String` do something like this `Map<String, String> toMap() => toJson().cast<String, String>();`. This will cause an error if the value be `null`